# Как передать токен пользователя сайта в telegram, что бы синхронизировать связать их?

Tags: php, telegram

задача следующая: Нужно как то связать пользователей моего сайта с их телеграм аккаунтами. Я так понимаю что мне нужно на сайте сделать какую то ссылку которая будет отправлять ползователя на моего бота + токен в виде get или post параметра. Я же получаю токен, сверяю его с базой, получаю id пользователя у себя на сайте и прописываю ему chat_id. Не могу понять как это реализовать, нашел что то такое https://telegram.me/<мой бот>?start=<токен>. Бот сейчас реализован через Webhook. Как мне получить в вебхуке этот самый токен?
Нужно что то типа того:

```
$bot = new TelegramBot\Api\Client(ид бота);
$bot->command('start', function ($message) use ($bot) {
if(токен){
    Тут выполняем привязку и после говорим что все норм
    $answer = 'Отлично бро, теперь тебе будут приходить оповещения! ;)';
    $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $answer);
}else{
    Тут говорим что не было токена и привязка не осуществилась
}
});
$bot->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Простейшим вариантом будет показывать пользователю ссылку, переходя по которой он будет привязывать текущую учётную запись к известному аккаунту, которому была отправлена ссылка.